# JVM terminated. Exit code=15

Tags: java, eclipse

We installed eclipse and X11.Dt filesets on AIX

However, when I try executing eclipse it throws exit-code=15.

```
[machine_name]:/opt/freeware/eclipse$ ./eclipse
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=15
/usr/java14/jre/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /opt/freeware/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os aix
-ws gtk
-arch ppc64
-showsplash /opt/freeware/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/freeware/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/freeware/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc64_1.1.100.v20120913-144808/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /opt/freeware/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 2740000b
-vm /usr/java14/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /opt/freeware/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Not sure what has gone wrong.  Please provide your suggestions to fix this issue

Should we install GTK Libraries on AIX?  Where can I see the log file for this runtime error ?

Comment: Did you installed the specific AIX eclipse ? there is one (not sure if it's the latest build for AIX) : http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.2-201302041200/aixPlatform.php

Comment: Are you really using Java 1.4? (/usr/java14/jre/bin/java)

Answer (score 0):

We installed the following filesets on our AIX box

```
atk-1.12.3-2.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
cairo-1.8.8-1.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
expat-2.0.1-1.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
fontconfig-2.4.2-1.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
freetype2-2.3.9-1.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
gettext-0.10.40-6.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
glib2-2.12.4-2.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
gtk2-2.10.6-4.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
libjpeg-6b-6.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
libpng-1.2.32-2.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
libtiff-3.8.2-1.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
pango-1.14.5-4.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
pixman-0.12.0-3.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
xcursor-1.1.7-3.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
xft-2.1.6-5.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
xrender-0.9.1-3.aix5.2.ppc.rpm
zlib-1.2.3-3.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
```

from the URL mentioned below

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21631478

which fixed the issue